# swift - Casting an Array vs an ArraySlice using protocols

Tags: arrays, swift

In this code snippet

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
extension Int: MyProtocol {}

let a: Array<MyProtocol> = Array<Int>()
let b: ArraySlice<MyProtocol> = a[...]
let c: Array<Int> = a as! Array<Int>
let d: ArraySlice<Int> = b as! ArraySlice<Int>
```

`d` warns with `Cast from 'ArraySlice<MyProtocol>' to unrelated type 'ArraySlice<Int>' always fails`.

Why can't a Slice be cast in the same way as the original Array? Can this snippet be modified to give the Array casting behaviour to the Slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically due to how generic variance in Swift works.

[Only few types are variant in Swift](https://medium.com/@aunnnn/covariance-and-contravariance-in-swift-32f3be8610b9), including `Array<T>` and `Set<T>`. Most other types, and the types you define, are invariant.

Invariance means that `T<A>` and `T<B>` are unrelated types even if `A` and `B` are related.

`Array<T>` and `Set<T>` are covariant, which means that a `Array<A>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Array<B>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`. You can force it to go the other way (like you did in the third line) by using `as!`.

`ArraySlice<T>`, like many other types, is simply invariant. You need to do this to convert:

```
let d: ArraySlice<Int> = ArraySlice(b.map { $0 as! Int })
```

Comment: I ran a quick performance check using your solution - pretty slow unfortunately.
Running the same code over 400000 elements gave the following
`A took 19.402432084083557`
`B took 0.9146029949188232`
`C took 0.8825139999389648`
`D took 16.287996888160706`

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum answer to the correct answer by @Sweeper for people who are looking for type-flexible performant copy-by-ref arrays, I ended up rolling a solution which wraps an array in a class and exposes some of the API for an array.

Not a great solution, but it does what I need it to. Boo Apple for not keeping their APIs for this sort of thing consistent.

```
class ArrayReference<T>: Collection {
    private(set) var array : Array<T>

    init(_ encapsulating: Array<T>? = nil) {
        self.array = encapsulating ?? []
    }

    var startIndex: Int {
        get {
            return array.startIndex
        }
    }

    var endIndex: Int {
        get {
            return array.endIndex
        }
    }

    var count : Int {
        get {
            return array.count
        }
    }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return array.index(after: i)
    }

    subscript (index: Int) -> T {
        get { return array[index] }
        set(newValue) { array[index] = newValue }
    }

    func append(_ newValue: T) {
        array.append(newValue)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        array.removeAll()
    }

    var first: T? {
        if array.count > 0 {
            return array[0]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var last: T? {
        if array.count > 0 {
            return array[array.count - 1]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func asType<C>(_ type: C.Type) -> ArrayReference<C>? {
        if let array = self.array as? Array<C> {
            return ArrayReference<C>(array)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension ArrayReference: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ArrayReference<T>, rhs: ArrayReference<T>) -> Bool {
        if lhs.count == rhs.count {
            var equal = true
            for (lhs, rhs) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
                equal = equal && (lhs == rhs)
            }
            return equal
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```